# jQuery Multipage/One-page system

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to know how can I create a system using HTML, CSS and jQuery that simulates a multipage website using a single HTML page. One example of this feature is used in [this website](http://lema.ag).

Is there a plugin to create this effect and transition?

Comment: I recommend you poke around their source code. If you were to open functions.js and run the code through jsbeautifier.org you would have your answer.

Comment: Yes you can do it via some slider plugin + parallax plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the website link you have given here is actually a single page. There are many plugins to achieve what is happening there. one of them is

[reveal.js](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/) it also has an online presentation creator present [here](http://slid.es/)

other one is [impress.js](http://bartaz.github.io/impress.js/) but IE isnt supported